# Find angle $\alpha$ in equation containing weighted sum of $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\alpha)$.

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving, quantum-information

The context of this question comes from calculating the Fidelity drop of quantum systems after applying a rotation with some arbitrary angle $\alpha$ on the state vector of the system, see equation below:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta F = &sin(\alpha)&(\frac{(a_{1} + a_{4})(b_{2} + b_{3}) - (a_{2} + a_{3})(b_{1} + b_{4})}{2}) \nonumber \\
&-&cos(\alpha)(\frac{(b_{2} + b_{3})^{2} + (a_{2} + a_{3})^{2} - F}{2}) \nonumber \\
&+&(\frac{(b_{2} + b_{3})^{2} + (a_{2} + a_{3})^{2} - F}{2}) \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}$$

$\Delta F$, $F$, $a_i$ and  $b_j$, $1\leq i,j\leq 4$ are known.

Could someone explain to me how I could get the angle $\alpha$, if that is even possible?

I will be very grateful for your help!

I have another similar problem, but with a weighted sum of $(cos(\alpha))^{2}$,  $(sin(\alpha))^{2}$, and $cos(\alpha)sin(\alpha)$ in which I could also get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us have the general (and prettier) equation $$B=m\sin\alpha -n\cos \alpha+K.$$
Transpose $K$ and divide the whole equation by $\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$:$$\frac{B-K}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}=\frac{m}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2} }\sin\alpha-\frac{n}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2} }\cos\alpha$$
Now, $\Bigg |\dfrac {m}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}\Bigg |<1$ and so there must exist some angle A such that $\cos A= \dfrac {m}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$ and also $\sin A= \dfrac {n}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$ and $\tan A=\dfrac nm$. We have now,
$$\frac{B-K}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}=\sin\alpha\cos A-\cos\alpha\sin A=\sin (\alpha-A).$$ Thus, $$\alpha=A+\arcsin\left(\frac{B-K}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}\right)$$$$=\arctan\frac nm+ \arcsin\left(\frac{B-K}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}\right).$$

EDIT: Comparing the general equation to the OP’s equation, we have $K=n$.

Comment: I suggest you make the last paragraph a separate question. Asking multiple questions in a single post is against community policy.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try the solution in my program and give you feedback on how it worked!...and thanks for the comment.

Comment: Why $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{m^{2} + n^{2}}}$$ is not restricted as the weight of the sinus fuction?

Comment: What exactly, do you mean by “restricted”?

Comment: I understand that the weight of the sinus must be less than 1(thus restricted) as follows $$\Bigg | \frac{m}{\sqrt{m^{2} + n^{2}}}\Bigg | < 1$$ I would think the same for the weight of the cosinus function.

Comment: Yes, of course; I haven’t mentioned it explicitly, but what you said  _is_ true. I only mentioned the first one because it was a  necessary observation to invoke the equality with the sine of some angle. This method was the most obvious and intuitive for me. As an alternative way, you could also start with $\dfrac {n}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$ and proceed to the solution.

Comment: Also, By the way, I have rejected your edit of “K=n” because I have tried to cater to the most general case possible. It might be true that K=n in your question, but that was not my intent. I have generalised the equation. However, I have added K=n in an edit to the answer.

Comment: Thank, the implementation of the rotational channel works perfectly !

Comment: @LeonardoGonzalez really happy for you! 